# Convert JSON object into single one variables

Tags: javascript, python, json, api

i have made a POST request using ajax. But i am receiving my data like this

```
[{u'name': u'cuenta', u'value': u'01050160181244049'}, {u'name': u'beneficiario', u'value': u'xxxxxxx'}, {u'name': u'identificador', u'value': u'V'}, {u'name': u'identidad', u'value': u'2423439'}, {u'name': u'email', u'value': u'dfgfdgfd@gmail.com'}, {u'name': u'monto', u'value': u'1'}, {u'name': u'concepto', u'value': u'pago'}]
```

I need to process that on my backend but i need to have it on this way

```
{
"cuenta": "010501601811634534549",
"beneficiario": "xxxxxxx",
"identificador": "V",
"identidad": "23432423",
"email": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
"monto": "1",
"concepto": "pago"
}
```

How can i convert it? or how i can send my ajax request with the normal format that i need? here is my code of js

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var frm = $('#formulario_datos');
frm.submit(function (e) {
    frm.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = JSON.stringify($("#formulario_datos").serializeArray());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/transferencia',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Message);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error!!!");
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType : "application/json"
    });
});
```

});

Comment: You need to show the python code that composes the JSON reply. That JS code is irrelevant to the question. (also, there's no such thing as a JSON object)

Comment: You'd better fix the Python part rather than do extra coding for the conversion.

Comment: Ok thank you i fixed my code in js to send the data properly. This is my code on python global cuenta_actual

 post_data = request.get_json()

 if cuenta_actual == "" or cuenta_actual == post_data.get('cuenta'):

  cuenta_actual = post_data.get('cuenta')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to `reduce` into an object, extracting the `name` and `value` properties from each item in the array:

```js
// const arr = $("#formulario_datos").serializeArray();
const arr = [{'name': 'cuenta', 'value': '01050160181244049'}, {'name': 'beneficiario', 'value': 'xxxxxxx'}, {'name': 'identificador', 'value': 'V'}, {'name': 'identidad', 'value': '2423439'}, {'name': 'email', 'value': 'dfgfdgfd@gmail.com'}, {'name': 'monto', 'value': '1'}, {'name': 'concepto', 'value': 'pago'}];

const transformedObj = arr.reduce((a, { name, value }) => {
  a[name] = value;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(transformedObj);

/*
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/transferencia',
  data: JSON.stringify(transformedObj),
  ...
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` comprehension on the result. This is an example you can try in REPL:

```
>>> result = [
        {u'name': u'cuenta', u'value': u'01050160181244049'}, 
        {u'name': u'beneficiario', u'value': u'xxxxxxx'}, 
        {u'name': u'identificador', u'value': u'V'}, 
        {u'name': u'identidad', u'value': u'2423439'}, 
        {u'name': u'email', u'value': u'dfgfdgfd@gmail.com'}, 
        {u'name': u'monto', u'value': u'1'},
        {u'name': u'concepto', u'value': u'pago'}]
>>> {e["name"]: e["value"] for e in result}
{u'beneficiario': u'xxxxxxx', u'monto': u'1', u'identificador': u'V', u'concepto': u'pago', u'cuenta': u'01050160181244049', u'identidad': u'2423439', u'email': u'dfgfdgfd@gmail.com'}
```